# How to correctly wrap Google Closure UI Component as Rum Component

Tags: reactjs, clojurescript, google-closure-library

I would like to use Google Closure UI components from ClojureScript with the Rum/React library.

I started with goog.ui.DatePicker, but still cannot wrap it correctly. The code underneath renders the DatePicker once on component mount and at the right place, the event listener works and all is fine, except it needs the statically set id ("here") at the dom node to work which would be acceptable for one time hack, but not when I need to have the component wrapped and use several times on the same page/app.

```
(ns redux.components
  (:require [rum.core :as r]
            [cljs-time.core :as time]
            [cljs-time.format :as tf]
            [goog.dom :as dom]
            [goog.ui.DatePicker :as goog-picker]
            [goog.events :as goog-events]]))

   (r/defcs +published-at < { :did-mount (fn [state]
                   (let [target-node  (:r/ref state "here")
                         dp (goog.ui.DatePicker. nil goog.i18n.DateTimeSymbols_cs)]
                   (.listen dp (.. goog.ui.DatePicker -Events -CHANGE) #(println "new date is: " (tf/unparse (tf/formatter "YYYY-MM-dd")(time/to-default-time-zone (.. % -target getDate)))))
                   (.render dp (goog.dom/getElement "here")))
                   state) }
        []
        [:div#here])

   (r/defc app
        []
        [:div
           [:h1 "title"
              (+published-at)]])
```

## My further unsuccessful research

React [documentation suggests](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) that for integration with third-party DOM libraries one might need refs. Rum [documentation describes](https://github.com/tonsky/rum#interop-with-react) how to do react refs from Rum. But the trouble is that React doc states that string refs are legacy and might be removed in future releases while Rum documentation does not cover callback based refs. I tried to guess how to combine both frameworks with string refs as well as callback refs, but neither one seems to work:

### String based legacy approach

```
(r/defcs +published-at < { :did-mount (fn [state]
               (let [target-node  (:r/ref state "here")
                     dp (goog.ui.DatePicker. nil goog.i18n.DateTimeSymbols_cs)]
               (.listen dp (.. goog.ui.DatePicker -Events -CHANGE) #(println (tf/unparse (tf/formatter "YYYY-MM-dd")(time/to-default-time-zone (.. % -target getDate)))))
               (.render dp target-node))
               state) }
     []
     [:div
      [:div { :ref "here" } ]])
```

This fails with error and the DatePicker is not even displayed:

```
Uncaught TypeError: opt_parentElement.insertBefore is not a function
    at goog.ui.DatePicker.goog.ui.Component.render_ (component.js:705)
    at goog.ui.DatePicker.goog.ui.Component.render (component.js:659)
    at Function.<anonymous> (components.cljs?rel=1493075625598:123)
    at Function.cljs.core.apply.cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$3 (core.cljs:3694)
    at cljs$core$apply (core.cljs:3676)
    at util.cljc?rel=1492772300984:17
    at core.cljs:2314
    at Function.cljs.core.seq_reduce.cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$3 (core.cljs:2314)
    at cljs.core.LazySeq.cljs$core$IReduce$_reduce$arity$3 (core.cljs:3287)
    at Function.cljs.core.reduce.cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$3 (core.cljs:2358)
```

### Callback base approach

```
(r/defcs +published-at < { :did-mount (fn [state]
               (let [dp (goog.ui.DatePicker. nil goog.i18n.DateTimeSymbols_cs)]
               (.listen dp (.. goog.ui.DatePicker -Events -CHANGE) #(println (tf/unparse (tf/formatter "YYYY-MM-dd")(time/to-default-time-zone (.. % -target getDate)))))
               (.render dp (::put-date-here state)))
               state) }
     [state]
     [:div
      [:div { :ref #(assoc state ::put-date-here %) }]])
```

This renders functional DatePicker, but out of the component, at the end of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `:did-mount` here, just render it right in the callback. This works fine for me:

```
(defn show-datepicker
  [d]
  (let [dp (goog.ui.DatePicker. nil goog.i18n.DateTimeSymbols_cs)]
    (.listen dp (.. goog.ui.DatePicker -Events -CHANGE)
             #(js/console.info
                (.. % -target getDate)))
    (.render dp d)))


[:div {:ref show-datepicker}]
```

If you need to tear down the datepicker then just check for `(nil? d)` in your `show-datepicker`. React will pass nil when the component unmounts.

PS: I wound't use `cljs-time` unless you really like big js output files.